# Necessary to define constructor that doesn't initialize anything?

Tags: php, oop, constructor

If you have a class with a constructor that doesn't initialize anything, is it necessary to define the constructor? Is it good or bad practice to omit empty constructors? Are there any notable side-effects?

For example:

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    private $bar;

    public function __construct() {
        // No initialization logic
    }

    // ... rest of class 
}
```

Comment: If your extending other classes a blank constructor will cover any inherited constructor so it can cause problems.

Comment: If class extends another class - then defining/not defining a constructor can influence your code. Otherwise - skip empty constructor, do not make code complicated.

Comment: No, it is not necessary. This is not particularly hard to test. Regarding good & practice, that's a matter of opinion.

Answer (score -1):

For best practice you should always put an empty constructor then it is up to your needs if you want to add a constructor with parameters.

Comment: _Why_ is it best practice? I didn't downvote your answer BTW.

Comment: I did, because this answer has no basis, sources, or explanation.  Constructors are not necessary and when using inheritance, empty constructors actually can break your code as suggested in the comments.

Comment: @Devon For me i always make empty construction at the beginning  because sometimes i don't need to initiate constructor with parameters

Comment: @HamzaTorjmen if you don't need to inject dependencies (or parameters as you say), why write out the constructor at all then?   When you start developing large applications, you'll find that a lot of your classes will be extending other classes.